# checkout TFS files in windows 7 through SSMS and other "Open" dialogs

Tags: ssms, tfs-power-tools

When I was working on TFS with Windows XP. I was able to execute TFS Commands through the context menu when I had a open dialog box window open in SSMS and other applications. but once I upgraded to Windows 7. I only can Check-out ,check-in , etc... files through Windows Explorer. I have The TFS Power tools and Side kick installed. Is it because Windows 7 dialogue boxes are coded differently then Windows Explorer?

I am Using:
TFS 2010 
SQL Management Studio 2008

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done so already, get the latest [Visual Studio 2010 Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f)

This is the latest and greatest release of power tools, August 2011.

I too have VM Win7 with Team Explorer and a VM with Win7/VS2010 Ultimate.  Both with the latest power tools and do not have any issues through the context menu.

Power Tools does not do an in place upgrade. It requires that the prior version of power tools be uninstalled before installing a newer version.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I tried a re-install of the TFPT and a reboot, but still nothing on my Win7 x64 desktop.

Comment: I tried that as well, i unistalled all the version of power tools and installed the above link power tools and no luck